# Find statistical significance for average of variables estimatod in different regressions

Tags: regression-coefficients, mean

I have estimated GARCH 20 times for 20 companies in EViews with the normal distribution.

I have used a dummy variable which is 1 during specific events to see if the conditional volatility is higher during the event.

The 20 companies are supposed to represent an industry and what I want is an industry average of the dummy variable. I have the coefficient, standard error and z-Statistic for each company.

What I need is to generate significance information of the industry average based on the S.E and/or the z-Statistic of respective companies. I would prefer to import my values in Excel and run the calculation there so what I need is the formula. Can anyone provide this information? Thank you.